# php regex preg_match: less than and less than equal to not working

Tags: php, regex

So this is my `preg_match` code,

```
preg_match("/>=|<=|>|</", $value)
```

So whenever user input something like `'<50' or '<=50' or '>50' or '>=50'`, I can get their input and send to my query

My `>=` and `>` works well, but less than and less than equal to are not working properly.

Sorry, the `<=<` and `<<` are my try, I modified back

Thank you.

Comment: Umm, just try [`/>=|<=|>|</`](https://regex101.com/r/m0AhKT/1) I don't see how you can expect to match `<=` from `<=<`

Comment: Try this `[<>]=?`

Comment: One of the alternatives matches `<=<`. Probably you want `"/[<>]=?|<</"` or just what ctwheels suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`preg_match("/[><]=?[\d]+/", $value)`.

I am assuming you want your regex to not just check for `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, but also you want it to check if any number(s) also follow after any of the above symbols.

So the following values for `$value` should work:

`<=50` or `<50` or `>50` or `>=50`

However simply passing `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=` would not work.

To make it optional for it to track any numbers at the end you may simple have to change the end of expression from `+` (i.e 1 or More) to `*` (i.e. 0 or more). Which would look like:

`"/[><]=?[\d]*/"`